# M1 Mac Mini Fails to Shutdown with APC UPS Options (Monterey 12.2.1)

Tags: mac-mini, shutdown, apple-silicon, ups

I have an M1 Mac Mini that needs to auto-shutdown after 60 seconds on the UPS. We are using an APC Back-Ups 850VA model connected via USB.

Also, this M1 mac mini has had its data migrated from a Time Machine backup of an Intel Mac Mini running OS X El Capitan 10.11.6.

The mac properly recognizes the UPS and lists the UPS options in the Energy Saver preferences, however no matter what I set within the UPS settings, the UPS does not shutdown the machine.

The only thing that does work is a warning when the Mac Mini is drawing from the UPS.

**Does anyone have any suggestions?  Nothing in the previous threads have worked.**

Here are the relevant settings:

**pmset -g**

```
System-wide power settings:
Currently in use:
 disksleep            10
 powernap             1
 womp                 1
 networkoversleep     0
 sleep                0 (sleep prevented by coreaudiod, bluetoothd, powerd)
 Sleep On Power Button 1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 tcpkeepalive         1
 autorestart          1
 standby              0
```

**pmset -g ups**

```
UPS settings:
  haltlevel on  100
  haltafter on  1
  haltremain    on  15
```

**When UPS plugged in:**

```
Now drawing from 'AC Power'
 -Back-UPS ES 850G2 FW:931.a10.D USB FW:a10 (id=25296896)   74%; charging present: true
```

**When ups unplugged:**

```
Now drawing from 'UPS Power'
 -Back-UPS ES 850G2 FW:931.a10.D USB FW:a10 (id=25296896)   74%; discharging; 4:14 remaining present: true
```

Comment: +1, I have an M1 Mac Mini connected to a Smart-UPS (SMTL750RMI2UC), when I am connected via screen sharing I get disconnected, but the LED on the front remains on, suggesting it goes to sleep but does not shut down. (Unfortunately I currently have no access to the machine to check the console to confirm exactly what happens).

Answer (score 1):

I also have an Apple Mac Mini M1 and I purchased a UPS (Eaton 5E Essential UPS) with USB connection yesterday and it does exactly the same thing as you're reporting here. To further test this, I purchased a second UPS unit from another brand (ChasePower Opal 850 - that specifically lists Mac OS compatibility) and it also only reports that the UPS is drawing power from the UPS (when unplugged from mains power) and will not shut the computer down no matter what options I try.

Unless there are other solutions out there that I haven't been able to find, it appears that this functionality may be currently broken on OSX (12.2.1) with the M1 chip at least. My Mac Mini was freshly installed with OSX when purchased in late 2021 so I don't think your time machine migration is a necessarily a factor.

I have an older (2012) Mac Mini Intel version at my office and I might try these UPS units with that next week to confirm if this issue doesn't happen with that processor (won't be the latest version of OSX however).

Please let me know if you have any luck getting this to work as this functionality is needed with a UPS.

Regards, Paul